# I am concerned an answer I gave will mislead others?

Tags: discussion, answers

A senior community member left a comment stating [my answer was incomplete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-12-04-lts/126513#126513), even though it worked for me when I tested on my machine. The components he stated were missing were actually installed correctly on my machine.  I do not want to be misleading other members if my answer is incorrect. I prepared a response to the comment (quoted below) but thought but  I would approach Meta first for advice on how to handle before I add it (dont want things to get ugly) and the answer is starting to get down voted.

There are 2 options

1. Remove the question and answer (as it worked for me only) and won't.
   benefit others
2. Update the answer with the correct resolution (something I personally cannot do).

**Proposed response to the comment**
@Bruno, I just read your comment and checked out what you state I was missing (according to your comment note).  FYI, I appear to have a fully working video driver. But I am not technical and I need to trust the community to help me on this.

Firstly, I went to Synaptic Manager and lib32gccl, libc6-i386 & ia32-libs-multiarch where already installed (they were not missing).

Secondly, I also ran the `sudo` code you said I was missing [(see the output)](http://pastebin.com/eCrFScpg) As you can see output stated I already have the newest version(s).

I have 2 objectives here,

1. To make sure my video drivers are installed correctly on my machine. (if they are not, I need the communities assistance).
2. To make sure others can benefit from this Question and answer (without confusion).

I ran the code in the from the Ubuntu Document community it was trouble free and I had no issues, everything performed as described and I appear to have a fully working video driver.  I need someone (anyone) from the community to give me the correct answer, as I do not want to leave a legacy were others will fail by reading this Q&A..  If what I have done is incorrect I want to avoid future issues  please update the answer with what is right (but please test it first) as I did.

Comment: It's awesome that you're taking good care of this question by asking how to help, we need more of that around here!

Comment: +1 for your responsibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its great and all but the necessary packages are *not installed* by default in a standard 64bit installation, you need to make sure that the instructions you are telling will make everyone happy in the end, so yeah probably you will need to include all those packages according to the documentation else we end up with a half answer.

I was going to update the one I did with instructions to 12.04 as soon as it is released but you beat me up to it, and with a great title and instructions! That is so nice to see in Ask Ubuntu.

I took some time and read the driver release documentation and those are the listed packages according to AMD that should be installed in a Ubuntu 12.04 system and the 2nd part or the list for a Ubuntu 12.04 64bit one.

I installed 12.04 in a vbox and updated the packages to latest and tried to install all those packages from start, all of them except for 1 or 2, all are missing from a clean install, so that probably means that you had them already installed because of some other attempt you did. All those packages are necessary (according to AMD) to install the driver.

We can do 2 things, nothing or fix your answer so I can link it in to mine so people are redirected to yours when they look at it. I would rather see the 2nd :/

In the end its up to you, I think that just because it worked with you and because you say that you already had those packages installed that the answer should be fixed with the missing packages so we can support on it when people need to install the binary driver in 12.04. I dropped a comment with the missing packages from a clean install, even if 1 or 2 are already installed those are the total packages needed. They should be included in the answer.

So, without confusing and without discussion on what state your machine was before you installed the driver (the issue is not if it worked for you or not), we should make sure that those packages are installed by default on a system when installing the driver.

Comment: I agree Bruno and rely on your wisdom to do the right thing.  I will leave it up to you to take action with what will serve the community best.  Thanks for your due dilligence

Comment: @StephenMyall if we fix that for now I will just link to you for 12.04 instructions! Sorry for the small talks, time is really an issue for me atm.

Comment: Whatever works best, keep up the great work